# ArangoDB LIKE function doesn't seem to filter out values containing '*'

Tags: arangodb

Collection named "PatternInfo" contains following documents:

`1. { "pattern": "abcde*fgh"}
2. { "pattern": "test*new" }
3. { "pattern": "abc%^def" }`

Whenever the following query is run to filter patterns containing '*' empty results is returned.

`for doc in PatternInfo
filter like(doc.pattern, "%test*n%", false)
return doc`

I have even tried escaping '*', although the ArangoDB documentation for LIKE specifies only '%' and '_' to be escaped.

Is something wrong with the query or ArangoDB itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in the C++ implementation of `LIKE()`.

The V8 implementation produces the expected results in my test:

```
for doc in PatternInfo
filter noopt(v8(like(doc.pattern, "%test*n%", false)))
return doc
```

It matches 2. `{ "pattern": "test*new" }` correctly.

I created a bug report on your behalf:
https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/4919